# Centering absolute div inside relative div, which width is set in percentage

Tags: css, css-position, percentage

I need those div to build a jQuery slideshow.
The divx div contain images. The left column (.left) contains the slider which is filling the entire column width.
How can I center the images inside the #divx(they have different sizes)?

```
<div class = "left">

<p> Bla bla.</p>
<div id = "slider">
    <div>
   <img src="img/johndoe.png">  
   </div>
   <div>
   <img src="img/johndoe2.png">  
   </div>
</div> <!--end of slider-->

</div> <!--end of left-->
```

And the CSS

```
.left {
margin-top:1%;
margin-left:1%;
max-width:48%;
float:left;
padding:1%;
}

#slider {
position:relative;
width:100%;

}

#slider #divx {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The div around each image, create a css

```
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```